# Restricting output columns in GroupJoin LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Given 2 tables with a one to many relationship, I would like to do the following, getting the parent ID and the children's names as a nested list for each parent:

```
from p in parent
join c in child on p.ID equals c.ParentID 
into parentsChildren
select new {p.ID, parentsChildren.FirstName}
```

This first example does not compile. I know I can get the same result using the following SelectMany query, but would like to figure out the equivalent GroupJoin syntax from above.

```
from p in parent
let parentsChildren = from c in p.children
                select c.FirstName
select new{p.ID, parentsChildren}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from p in parent
join c in child on p.ID equals c.ParentID 
into parentsChildren
select new 
{
   p.ID, 
   ChildNames = parentsChildren.Select(c => c.FirstName) 
}
```